# Android Java Take All editText's at once

Tags: java, android

I have about 200 editText's in my xml file.

I want to take all input value's at once in my java file.

Is there any way I can do that without finding all 200 ids.

Comment: Please provide any example code ?

Comment: IMO, making the user type stuff into 200 edit texts is not very good UX. I will certainly be annoyed.

Comment: I agree with @Sweeper, that's definitely not a good UX. Maybe you can improve it by making a small number of edit text with paging.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private LinearLayout ll;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        ll=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_view);

        final int childcount = ll.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childcount; i++) {
            View v = ll.getChildAt(i);
            if (v instanceof EditText) {
                Log.d("EditText Value", ((EditText) v).getText().toString());
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To create 200 EditText in linearlayout

```
LinearLayout mRlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llMainLayout);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams mRparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            EditText myEditText = new EditText(context);
            myEditText.setLayoutParams(mRparams);
            mRlayout.addView(myEditText);
        }
```

To retrive values in arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> alEditTextInputs = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int j=0;j<mRlayout.getChildCount();j++){
        alEditTextInputs.add(((EditText)mRlayout.getChildAt(j)).getText().toString()); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make recursively call in your parent views to find a instance of `Edittext` in view.

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = //Your parent layout it render your child view.

int count = viewGroup .getChildCount();
for(int i =0;i<count;i++)
{
    View v = viewGroup .getChildAt(i);
    if(v instanceof Edittext)
    {
        // you got the edittext
        EditText s = (EditText) v;
        Log.i("Item selected",s.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this link**

1. [No More findViewById](https://medium.com/google-developers/no-more-findviewbyid-457457644885#.coxl1qkfq)
2. [Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)